# What does <?!= mean in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

On pages like 
https://github.com/google/google-apps-script-samples/blob/master/simple_tasks/Page.html I see code bracketed as shown:

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent(); ?>
```

What does `<?!=` to `?>` sequence mean? Does it translate to a direct call to Google Apps Script/Javascript on the server, in this case the global HtmlService object? Sort of like `<?php` when using PHP?

This appears to be impossible to search for using the Goog. I tried various quoting/escaping techniques without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called [scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets), and as you mentioned, just like in PHP or other templating language, in Google Apps Script you can mix code and HTML when using [HtmlTemplate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template) method in the [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service), they will be evaluated at the server side, before the content is returned to the client, you can call functions defined in other .gs files, reference global variables, almost any code you can run inside a .gs file.

They are pretty well documented in the [Official Developers Website](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#top_of_page), but in resume there are three types of scriplets:

- **[Standard scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#standard_scriptlets)** `<? ... ?>`: The code is executed without explicit output.
- **[Printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets)** `<?= ... ?>`: The code runs and outputs the results using contextual escaping.
- **[Force-printing scriptlets](http://%3C?!=%20...%20?%3E)** `<?!= ... ?>`: The code runs and outputs the results, but avoiding contextual escaping.

The documentation has a [simple example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript) of how to separate HTML, CSS and JavaScript using Templated HTML.

Comment: Fabulous. Thank you.