# Html tag beginning with question mark?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, tags

I'm learning google apps script, and in [this](https://blog.gsmart.in/parse-and-extract-data-from-gmail-to-google-sheets/) tutorial, I saw some weird looking syntax: `<? /* JS code */ ?>` and `<?= /* JS code */ ?>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>Message Display Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body style="padding:3em;">
  <h1>Messages</h1>
    <ul>
    <? for(var m=0;m<messages.length;m++){ ?>
    <li><?= messages[m].getSubject() ?></li>
    <p><?= messages[m].getPlainBody() ?></p>
    <? } ?>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can kind of understand what is going on, but I'm still confused. I've never seen these while learning HTML. How does this compare to script tags?

Comment: Friendly advice (no joking): do not learn via tutorials without reading official documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#index.html

Comment: Take a look here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

Comment: Before anyone else answers/comments that this is PHP... it’s not. Those tags are used in PHP but thats not the case here. See the link in the very first comment from @OlegValter above. It’s for Google Suite App Scripts.

Comment: @FluffyKitten - [tag:php] attacks, run! Joking aside, they do have a bit of a point, it does look like php tags (even the docs mention similarity). But, of course, the quesiton is not about them. I wonder, how could anyone find the question so fast? Neighter tags, nor content suggests it has anything to do with php...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510858/how-to-use-scriptlets-in-htmloutput-in-google-apps-script, tangentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843609/how-do-i-include-scripts-in-my-google-apps-script-google-sheets-html

Comment: @OlegValter I think it’s the html tag - html and PHP are often used together. Yes they are pretty much identical, that’s why I added my comment to let users know before anyone else added to the confusion:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google Apps Script `<? . . .?>` are called standar scriptlets, `<?= . . . ?>` are printed scriptlets  and `<?!= . . . ?>` are force printing scriplets. They are used in Google Apps Script HTML Service templated HTML.

Resource

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Related

- [How to use scriptlets in HTMLOutput in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27510858/1595451)
- [What does <?!= mean in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39360247/1595451)

Answer (score -2):

The question mark is used for PHP and is incorporated into html to work. It is another programming language related to web design. PHP is mainly used to make more advanced form system.

Comment: Those tags are used in PHP but it’s not PHP in this case. See the link in Oleg’s comment on the question.

Comment: This question is not about PHP and the "question mark" is not exclusive of PHP.